# Extract objects by their properties from list of class names in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of Class names: `obj_list = ["Fruit", "Vegetable"]`
and I need to iterate over them and find all object that have `color` attribute set to `red` (assuming that both Fruits and vegetables has this attribute).

Comment: post what you have done so far

Comment: a.each{|c| Kernel.get_const(c).where(color = "red")}

Comment: It's `const_get` and do you have a `where` method defined for the classes?

Comment: Also, is the `color` attribute a class attribute or object attribute?

Comment: Instead `.where(color = "red")` you can try someth about: `.select { |fruit| fruit.color == 'red'`

Comment: Are Fruit and Vegetable Rails models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sets `@fruits` with the list of `Fruit` Objects matching `color: 'red'` and `@vegetables` the list of `Vegetable` Objects matching `color: 'red'`

```
obj_list = ["Fruit", "Vegetable"]

obj_list.each do |c|
  list_name = "@#{c.downcase}s"
  list_objects = Object.const_get(c).where(color: 'red')
  instance_variable_set(list_name, list_objects)
end

@fruits #=> Fruit.where(color: 'red')
@vegetables #=> Vegetable.where(color: 'red')
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this ways as well:

```
obj_list = ["Fruit", "Vegetable"]

obj_list.each_with_object(Array.new){ |object, array| array.push(object.constantize.send(:where, {color: 'red'})) }
```

It will be the array of Active Record relations, containing fruits and vegetables.

Comment: `each_with_object(Array.new)` with `push` is just `map`.